# Python pathlib match function doesn't work

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

pathlib `match(pattern)` is documented as matching a path against a provided glob-style pattern but it doesn't work

```
>>> Path("w/x/y/z").mkdir(parents=True)
>>> list(Path().glob("w/**/z"))
[PosixPath('w/x/y/z')]
>>> Path("w/x/y/z").match("w/**/z")
False
```

Shouldn't that return true?

Comment: I looked in pathlib.py (Python 3.7 -- look in lib), and aside from splitting the pattern by separator, it does no separate processing for `**`. `glob()` is typically used to search directory paths which yield multiple matches, but `match()` is used to compare specific cases. Does Path("w/x/y/z").match("w/*/*/z") work?

Comment: @BenY Ya, that works. `rglob()` does what he wants

Comment: To plainly state my point, as it appears to have been lost, is that `match()` does not work the same as `glob()` or `rglob()`. It's not implemented to treat `**` as a special match for multiple levels of directories. The answer is No, as @myz540 states.

Answer (score 0):

The glob pattern of `**` does not go through path delimiters. At least the `path.match()` function does not have it implemented. Maybe try `path.rglob()` which does recursive globbing.

Try:

```
In [1]: from pathlib import Path

In [2]: p = Path("w/z/y/z")

In [3]: p.mkdir(parents=True)

In [5]: p.match("w/*/*/z")
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: I already mentioned that you can use `rglob`. Not acceptable for what? Your question does not propose a use-case. You asked if `match()` should return `True` given the glob-style pattern and the answer is no.

Comment: `Path.match` is for checking a _string_ against a pattern. `Path.rglob` is for finding files on a filesystem which match a pattern. Those are totally different things, for using match you might not even have a filesystem available at all e.g. processing paths taken from a csv file or database.

Comment: So why do you think `Path("w/x/y/z").match("w/**/z")` shouldn't return True? It matches the glob pattern, doesn't it?

Comment: This also returns true: `Path("w/x/y/z").match("z")`, so I don't think it has anything to do with the asterisks - however, I'd expect it to require this to evaluate to true: `Path("w/x/y/z").match("**/z")`.